# Django custom login form not displaying inputfields

Tags: python, django, django-login

I have a problem with my login template. I´m not sure, but I think I´m using a custom form since the path is templates/registration/login.html . So, I think it gets replaced to the usual django form. But the input fields of my form dont show up, so I only have the login button and some text underneath it. Similar questions I read couldn´t solve it, so I hope someone can me help here. If you need any code more, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

views.py

```
def login(response):

if response.method == "POST":
    form = LoginForm(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        auth_login(response,user)
        return redirect("home")
else:
    form = LoginForm()
    
return render(response, "registration/login.html",{})
```

urls.py

```
from register import views as v

path("", v.login, name="login"),
```

login.html

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="content">
    
    <h3>{{form.username}}</h3>
    <h3>{{form.password}}</h3>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
<br>
<p>Don´t have an account yet?</p>
<p>Create one <a href="/signup">here</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render() function takes the request object as its first argument, a template name as its second argument and a dictionary as its optional third argument.

so, you should pass `{"form": form}` as the third argument to the render function.