# How to properly render form fields with django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on a login page for a django webapp. I am trying to include the login form within the index.html file. However, the form fields are not being rendered. My urls are correct I believe but I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Here is my views.py, forms.py and a snippet of the index.html. (I do not want to create a new page for the login I'd like to keep it on the index page)

```
# Home view
def index(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        user = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
        )
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f' welcome {user} !!')
            return redirect('loggedIn')
        else:
            messages.info(request, f'Password or Username is wrong. Please try again.')
    return render(request, "index_logged_out.html")
```

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=63)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=63, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

```
<!-- Login -->
            <section class="page-section" id="login">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Login</h2>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form}}
                        <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block fa-lg gradient-custom-2 mb-3" type="submit" style="width: 300px;">Login</button></center>
                    </form>
                    <div class="text-center pt-1 mb-5 pb-1">
                        <center><a class="text-muted" href="#!">Forgot password?</a></center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-4">
                        <p class="mb-0 me-2">Don't have an account?</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Create New</a></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68699523/django-custom-login-form-not-displaying-inputfields. For those that were wondering

Answer (score 0):

To add to A.S's answer, you should initialize a context variable at the start of the view.

```
def index(request):
context = {}
form = LoginForm()
context['form'] = form
if form.is_valid():
    # ...
return render(request, "index_logged_out.html", context)
```

It makes it easier to work with when you start to pass in more variables to the context later on, otherwise it'll complicate your view.